# How to make container in tablview fixed?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have tablview and in tablview i add containerview. I need to make containerview position fixed. How i can do it?
[image]

Comment: you have position of that container fixed

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I offten use `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`,

Then drag a `UITableView` and a `ContainerView` in it. Fix them use constrain.

Wish this may help!